# Building ionic app with cordova cli

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've just started to use the v1.0.1 of the ionic framework (by manually including the ionic css and js files and changing my directives to ionic directives) with a existing Cordova/Angular app for iOS/Android. My build infrastructure is currently setup to use the Cordova cli tools (v5.0) and I'd prefer to not change it if possible.

Is there any reason I shouldn't continue building my app using the Cordova cli rather than swapping to the ionic cli? Are there any potential compatibility issues? I understand that ionic is just a layer on top of Angular so it shouldn't have any effect on the app build process so building with Cordova should be ok?

Comment: No any issue you can use Cordova cli. My two application on Play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on the [ionic-cli github page](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/0bce662fe7bc5b84f1c521e5d491f54da514a1b0/README.md):

> Ionic uses Cordova underneath, so you can also substitute Cordova commands to prepare/build/emulate/run, or to add additional plugins.

So it's fine to use Cordova to build it.

Comment: Erm, Sam, haven't I actually answered the same thing?

Comment: @Nikola You showed that the ionic commands produce similar output to the Cordova commands but I still had concerns that the ionic commands might do other things apart from running underlying Cordova commands. This answer removes that ambigiuity a bit more IMO. I appreciate your help though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, building with Cordova CLI will be perfectly fine - Ionic actually uses Cordova in the backend.

So, for example `ionic plugin add http://github.com/somePlugin` does basically the same thing as `cordova plugin add http://github.com/somePlugin`.

Below you can see my terminal output, to affirm what I said above:

```
C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\test\plugintest>cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera/-/cordova-plugin-camera-1.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera/-/cordova-plugin-camera-1.2.0.tgz

C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\test\plugintest>cordova plugin list
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"

C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\test\plugintest>ionic plugin list
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.4 "Keyboard"
cordova-plugin-camera 1.2.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.0.1 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"

C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\test\plugintest>cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera
Removing "cordova-plugin-camera"

C:\Users\Nikola\Desktop\test\plugintest>ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera" via npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-plugin-camera
Saving plugin to package.json file
```

However, ionic cli has some additional features (like for example `ionic resources` to name at least one) which you may want to use to [generate splash screen and icons](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html).